# Double values are rounding in the dataset

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have ms access database.In that I have a table which the values are double data type.For example

```
Column 1
3.0
3.1
2.0
3.2
```

I am returning the values using data set from this table

```
  public DataSet GetDataSet(string sqlQuery)
    {
        //Initializes a dataset
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        //Specify Locale
        dataSet.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        Connection.Open();
        {                
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuery, this.connection);
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);
            adapter.Dispose();
        }
        Connection.Close();
        Connection.Dispose();

        return dataSet;
    }
```

But the values are getting rounded.The values which has .0 (ex: 3.0,2.0) return as 3,2.Is there any way to prevent the rounding of the double values.

Comment: 3.0 and 3 are the same value in `double` - there's no way of distinguishing between them.

Comment: yeap..
Can't I return the values as it is

Comment: How are you displaying them DataGrid, ListBox, Report etc. If you were to be more specific we could help you format them, which I'm sure is what you really care about.

Comment: I am converting the data set to the collection and generate a TOC using the collection

Comment: I agree with Jon Skeet and Conrad Frix. Your question is really about formatting, rather than rounding. Add some code that describes *how* you are presenting the data (i.e. what control is being used to present the data to the user), and then someone might be able to help you modify the formatting of the results.

Comment: I used CDbl(column1) and that method helps me some what..
Thanks for the support